# PHP: What does the '&' character mean?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

What does adding a '&' mean in this snippet I found?

```
$i = 10;
if($i&1){
    echo "$i is odd";
}
else {
    echo "$i is even";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the [bitwise AND](http://www.php.net/operators.bitwise) operator. in your case, it takes the binary representations of `10` and `1`  and performs the logical AND operation on the individual bits.

Answer (score 0):

That's a binray and. So for example 148 (binary 10010100) & 136 (binary 10001000) will be 128 (binary 10000000). So $i & 1 is either 1 (true) or 0 (false)